# array map split join, javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, join, split, array-map

I  need help in understanding this piece of code.
What is it doing and what is the type its returning. Possibly break it in smaller chunks to understand.

Why would it join array elements on '.' and then split them using the same dilimentor'.' What type of array is being passed back from search results?

```
    function getRandomInt(max, min = 0) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; // eslint-disable-line no-mixed-operators
    }

const searchResult = query =>
  new Array(getRandomInt(5))
    .join('.')
    .split('.')
    .map((item, idx) => {
      const category = `${query}${idx}`;
      return {
        value: category,
        label: (
          <div
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
          >
            <span>
              Found {query} on{' '}
              <a
                href={`https://s.taobao.com/search?q=${query}`}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                {category}
              </a>
            </span>
            <span>{getRandomInt(200, 100)} results</span>
          </div>
        ),
      };
    });
```

its been called like this

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState<SelectProps<unknown>["options"]>([]);

  const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
    setOptions(value ? searchResult(value) : []);
  };
```

I want to be able to put console.log to see what value is setOptions getting.
Thanks

```
----------------- Update 2-----------------
const searchResult = (query: string) => {
  const myArray = new Array(getRandomInt(5)).fill(0).map((item, idx) => {
    const category = `${query}${idx}`;
    return {
      value: category,
      label: labelElement(query, category),
    };
  });
  console.log(myArray);
  return myArray;
};


const labelElement = (query: string, category: string) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
      }}
    >
      <span>
        Found {query} on <a>{category}</a>
      </span>
      <span>{getRandomInt(200, 100)} results</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const [options, setOptions] = useState<SelectProps<unknown>["options"]>([]);

  const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
    setOptions(value ? searchResult(value) : []);
  };
```

Comment: It depends on whether or not the array contains strings with periods.

Comment: As you can see it is building an array actually and I think join is adding periods..But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we translate what `searchResult` does in plain English, I think it will be something like this:

> Generate & return an array of objects which length should be between 0 and 5 (including both values).
>
> Objects in array should have this shape:
>
> ```js
> {
>     value: string,
>     label: JSX.Element
> }
> ```

The trick with `.join('.').split('.')` seems to be needed to make array iterable with `.map`.
If you try to call `new Array(5).map(() => 'I am ignored ')` you will see that you'll get an empty array, and `.map(...)` part will be simply ignored.

That happens because `new Array(5)` returns an array of empty cells which are ignored by `.map(...)`. A more usual way to deal with it would be something like this:

```js
new Array(5).fill().map(() => 'Now it works!');
```

Comment: Thanks, I am checking this, get back with you as soon as I try your map example. Really need to get this figured out.

Comment: Also, why does map function have two parameters (item, idx), specially when we are not even using Item param?

Comment: @Sarah `item` is not used because it's an empty string, so it's not very useful. I think it's specified to get to `idx` because since `idx` is the second parameter, you simply can't access it without specifying the first one.

Comment: So, I tried new Array(5).map((e) => "sample string"); That worked good, but when I replace it in the code above like this new Array(getRandomInt(5)).fill().map((item, idx) => {}   It does not like the fill call.

Comment: @Sarah what exactly happens now? Does `searchResult` return anything? Any errors in console?

Comment: @Sarah also, please remember that `searchResult` may return an array with length 0. To avoid it, specify the min like this: `getRandomInt(5, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for helping out.. just a red squigly line under fill () with this error lib.es2015.core.d.ts(53, 10): An argument for 'value' was not provided.

Comment: @Sarah oh, ok, typescript wants us to explicitly specify some value for `.fill`. Let's put `.fill(0)` & it should work

Comment: thanks yes that worked. So in laymans term, its building a new array with size of say 5 and filling objects in the array.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, when I take the item param out it gives this error when the page renderes.. Does item, idx have to do anything with key value pairs?  react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `gh0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.

Comment: @Sarah yes, exactly, it just returns an array with several objects. Regarding the error, it indicates you that you provided duplicated [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to React, which is no good. I don't know how exactly you tried to take the first param out, but if you just left `(idx) =>`, it's not correct because `idx` is now always 0. Arguments can be named whatever, but their values depend on their position. So, if we rename arguments in `(pears, bananas) =>`, it will not matter. `pears` will always be 0 & `bananas` will be in 0-4 range

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did  did left (idx) => took "item" out. So it does sounds like its doing key,value pairs right? Because most of the examples that I have seen have only one argument with range(1, 9).map((idx) =>

Comment: Now if assign the array to a const variable and return it, it does not work.  How can I see the objects in the array before the array is returned?

Comment: Also help understanding this piece of code <SelectProps<unknown>["options"]>([]);

Comment: Actually I think based on your suggestions, I was just able to get the array object to print. See the code under update 2. Just need help with this piece of code ..  <SelectProps<unknown>["options"]>([]);

Comment: @Sarah regarding the key-value topic, I don't completely get the idea. It might be related topics but I don't see the connection. In general, it rather has a lot to do with [how map function works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Sarah you refactored it very well  regarding the piece of code: the last part `([])` is just initial vale for `options`. The rest is to explain to Typescript what option type actually is. Somewhere in your application there should be declared `SelectProps` generic type.